# What's the proper track to learning PCB Design?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I am a Computer Science guy. But recently I became interested in designing PCBs. I have done a few designs on Eagle. But they are quite basic. I tried to move forward, but PCB design just seems to be vast. There are books on High Speed Digital Design, and PCB Standards etc etc.

My first question is do PCB designers exist for separate domains ? If so, what are those domains?

Second, if I want to pursue a Design career in this, what kind of study track exist. I mean is it a masters level course in Electronics?  Or a masters level course in CAD/CAM ?

How do people start out ? I am having trouble with charting out a study track for designing PCBs.

Comment: "How do people start out" - in my experience it was basically picking up the basics from a colleague, self-teaching the rest and then eventually taking over from the colleague altogether.  Experience is probably more valuable than qualifications if you're eager to get a job at PCB design.  I did it the slow way, but it didn't cost me anything (in fact I was getting paid the whole time from the start).  I recommend just getting some designs under your belt and consider attempting to gain a proper qualification while you have a job in an electronics role that gives practical daily experience.

Comment: 2/2: I was a software engineer but a vacancy opened up in the hardware department of the same company.  I made the transfer and started out by doing some non PCB activities like checking Bills of Materials, parts sourcing, simple mechanical (enclosure) designs and then began to learn the basics of electronics and PCB layout.  If you're in a company that offers such an opportunity then it might be a very neat way to get into it.  PCB design as an occupation also requires knowledge of schematic design, component selection, and all the other things I was already doing in my new role.

Comment: I started off as a software engineer myself but electronics was my hobby. I worked on personal projects that required PCB design so I designed a bunch of my own boards, and moved on from there. I now work as a professional PCB designer. Start off with simple projects of your own and work your way up.

Answer (score 1):

**My first question is do PCB designers exist for separate domains ? If so, what are those domains?**

- A PCB Designer does exist for multiple separate domains.  For example, you can have a PCB designer that his main focus is High Speed Signal or another one that has more work experience in high power design.  At the end of the day, PCB designers work together as a team to get the best design possible.  Eventually, a PCB designer will become well rounded with tricky subjects like Mixed Split-planes, vias, and signal integrity.

**Second, if I want to pursue a Design career in this, what kind of study track exist. I mean is it a masters level course in Electronics? Or a masters level course in CAD/CAM ?**

- A typical Bachelor or Master in Electrical Engineering will get you the basics about PCB designing normally.  But for the most part, you will have to learn on your own to start off.  Upon landing an entry-level position with a PCB designer, you will work your way up and learn about those tools.  It all takes some time to become an expert in this domain but there is no real study track for designing PCBs.  Eagle is a good introductory tool to start off but you will want to become an expert with OrCad, Altium, or PADs in order to land a PCB designing position.

Comment: I startet off with the https://www.amazon.com/Complete-Design-Using-Capture-Editor/dp/0750689714 book. But it only briefs about designing. Can you tell me about any resources/ books which have a complete case study/ design walkthrough ( or whatever ) of may be popular boards/ soc’s or anything else good for that matter ?

Comment: There is a lot of material on the web to surf through... I would start with that first.  Then, begin designing your own small circuits focusing on different elements you want to learn whether it is focused more on digital, analog, or mixed-signals.  There are a few design walk-through on the web that could be useful but they are fairly basic designs.  I would also read about matching impedance, vias, and signal integrity if you want to go in digital design.  Quick tip, never put signal traces under an oscillator.